# SharePoint Designer 2010 - Approval task

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, approval-process

Under general settings with an approval task, you can choose to enable/disable certain commands on the task form: reassignment and request change. The thing is that I have multiple participants. Some of them need privileged rights.

1. Is there a way to enable/disable this on a more granular level, i.e. for the participants. Certain participants can request for a change, while others cannot. How can this be achieved? If not, what are good alternatives (e.g; third party tools)?
2. Is there a way that users can only reassign an item to a certain set of groups/users? How can this be achieved? If not, what are good alternatives (e.g; third party tools)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both of these can be achieved by editing the Approval.xsn InfoPath form. That can be found on the forms section of the parent workflow.

1. Either create a SharePoint group or just hardcode it into the Main (default) view of the InfoPath form: Manage Rules for the Reassign Task button, and add a Formatting rule to Hide this control when not(contains("*usernames*",xdUser:get-UserName()))
2. Same InfoPath form, but on the ReassignTask view. Open the People/Group Picker Properties of the Reassign Task To control. A General option defaults to Choose from: All Users but can be changed to Choose from: SharePoint Group.